# Maven multi-module + svn link for some modules

Tags: maven, svn

My task is to find the way linking some `<module>` with some trunk in svn. Is it possible?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>...</modelVersion>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>....</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>MyProjectAgg</name>
    <modules>
        <module>.....moduleFromSvn/trunk</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do with automatically checking out the `moduleFromSvn` every time your `MyProjectAgg` is checked out, to a desired location, say, on the same level as `module2` thru the use of `svn:externals`. See how to do that [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html).

Be sure to understand the implications of maintaining the `externals` properties on your projects, especially when you're faced with a need to update the link(s) to external projects. If you don't do it right, you could end up referencing old locations even after you've updated the links!

That way you don't need to duplicate code/projects in multiple locations, you instead reference it from where you need it. This also frees the maven up from trying to do something crazy - you just give it the module it needs, thanks to `svn`.